# Check if Cookie has Secure Flag set and update using JavaScript ONLY

Tags: javascript, security, cookies

My issue is we set some cookies, using JS, with a 1 year expiration and that particular cookie didn't have the secure flag set. We now want to update the cookies to have the secure flag set. The code that creates the cookies now has the "secure" attribute and all new cookies have the "secure" flag. The issue is how do I update existing cookies? I'm assuming I have to destroy the cookie and then recreate it with the secure flag set? I don't know if there is any other way to do this? Also is there a way using JavaScript to detect if the cookie does have the flag set before deleting it?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's a way to read the attributes of a cookie in standard Javascript (extensions can do it, but they use a browser-specific API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check cookies flags with pure JavaScript. If you want to add flag, just create a new one cookie and browser will overwrite old.

Example:

Type in console:

```
const year = 60*60*24*365;
document.cookie = 'mytestcookie=1;max-age='+year;
```

And look into cookies tab in your browser developer tools. You will see it's insecure.
Now, type:

```
document.cookie = 'mytestcookie=2;max-age='+year+';secure';
```

Look again.

Comment: So I will have to delete and then recreate the cookie first, if it hasn't expired, since the current code will only read it if it already exists and not try to write to it.

Comment: What @reski is saying is that , there is no need to delete a cookie, once you set the same cookie with new values the browser will just overwrite the old one.

Comment: Exactly, Soumen.

Comment: I understand what he is saying. My point is the cookies won't get over-written until they expire.